# TypeScript conditional type resolution and optional properties

Tags: typescript

**What I'm try to obtain:**

(I use an example to be more quick and clear)

```
// a function func which works with all following tests
function func<...>(opts: { inOpt?: boolean }): ... {}

// test suite 1
const t1 = func({ inOpt: false });
t1.outOpt = 0; // OK if lecit
t1.outOpt = "0"; // OK if error
t1.outOpt = undefined; // OPTIONAL OK if error

// test suite 2
const t2 = func({ inOpt: true });
t2.outOpt = 0; // OK if error
t2.outOpt = "0"; // OK if lecit
t2.outOpt = undefined; // OPTIONAL OK if error

// test suite 3
const t3 = func({});
t3.outOpt = 0; // OK if lecit
t3.outOpt = "0"; // OK if error
t3.outOpt = undefined; // OPTIONAL OK if error
```

**What I've tried:**

I did several attempts, the function declarations most close to what I need are:

```
// this makes test suites 1 and 2 to work
function func1<T extends boolean>(opts: { inOpt?: T }): { outOpt?: T extends true ? string : number } {
    return {};
}
```

```
// this makes test suit 3 to work
function func5<T extends boolean, R extends { inOpt?: T }>(opts: R): { outOpt?: R extends { inOpt: T } ? (T extends true ? string : number) : number } {
    return {};
}
```

I would have expected that simply `func1` to work: if `T` is not specified it doesn't `extends true`.

What I need is quite close to the example explained in the official TypeScript documentation, but the `?` to make the `inOpt` optional. What I need more to the official TypeScript documentation example is that when `inOpt` is not specified it is treated as if it was `false`, but after several attempts I feel I'm getting stuck.

Here is the [Playgroung](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/EQVwzgpgBGAuBOBLAxrYBuAUJgZiAdqogPb5R6ECMAPACpQQAesE+AJmFAEbHEA2EAIb4AfAApiAB1hgAXFADeURPgDy0gPzz6AXwCU8pcRCx1sLVHpMW7TghDQNMBCoDmUefhABbLhHhQOoqYUKFQ8BCwIPBkCjpYOtgURKTkBMgATHQMzKwc3LwCwuJSMobKapragQaKUMamVZY5NvkEbBA4KhBsUE5evv4ezdZ5dvAOfc5I+O6ePn4BQQohYRFRMYrxmIm46bAkZMkAzNmjtgX8QvgANFAASi1jdSpmFrol0nIPtUYmb-JgK9pMAnhcANYQACexBwDymYisuQu9kc0zcwwGiz0mIWQ2Wq1C62isW2u2SB1SyQALGdkfkeFdhHdHud8kpgeZqjpPmUfuUGgCoEDKmgwfkANqQmFw+4AXQRSNa40mTjgMzmUCx-hx80GS2CYXCkRJWwSSX2hzShAArHTlZcird4WzOBzRe9ArzvvdfvV-k1WfS3RUzNzFeKVWj1Ri9djcfrAoa1ibNnFzXtCJSjukAGz256Mp0syMvD3cu6qUuI0uoqYx2YJ7He+S+gUBrku4NlsPNIJOKtx-HJomp0kZgD0E6gyAAFsJXNBYLPEHZiFAWHAN7PoMkAHLWlL4MCYZCkLfJKAAXkPlCwmCnG4gW7AIEQLCglFP59gG8o18PMR3V7HBBD4SAaiwWBKAAOkFaQAIABnQKBH1UABpZQ4QEZB30waC4I7ADgEQjBUOnDCsIYeB4GIeB8Ng+DfxvdpOm6NgULQgAFWgAElVD3ABBAAZKBKMQOF-Fo+iH2nTdf1fd9oAyb9j1-WAMgA5IgNDaR5DrfQoIyQjGmYqBkPIsTMIk6jpPw4ymOI0jOIo6zsIgXDYHskyzAA1iunwHoXLEnj+KE0TxMkmi6OwR95JgN8P2OVSt1gY4tPSIDDPw44fIQm8LLQtyoBwvC0rysySLIoqqKkmLysclj2DYwKOMs1RQoEkSrNq6L6KAA) I used for my tests/attempts.

**Edit:**

Looking at the first two comments I received I try to explain by words what I need.

I need a function which takes as argument an object with an optional `inOpt` attribute of type `boolean` and returns an object with an optional `outOpt` attribute of type depending on `inOpt` value. The requirements is that the `outOpt` attribute must be:

- of type `number` when `inOpt` is `false`
- of type `string` when `inOpt` is `true`
- of type `number` when `inOpt` is not provided (treated as if it was `false`)

Comment: Could you please provide example of code which fails but you expect it to be ok. I understand you provided a lot of examples, but just for me it is a bit unclear.

Comment: Yeah, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Your examples are super confusing

Comment: You can try: `declare function foo<T extends { inOpt?: boolean }>(arg: T): T extends { inOpt: true} ? {outOpt: string} : {outOpt: number}`, if you want to use conditional  types.

Comment: Quite close @ford04, but when the input object start to have more options I'm finding some trouble. Probably I need to update my question to make it more close to the real use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try next example:

```js
// You can try simple function overloading
function foo(arg: { inOpt: true }): string;
function foo(arg: { inOpt: false }): number;
function foo(arg: {}): number;
function foo<T,>(arg: T) {
    return arg
}

const result = foo({inOpt:true}) // string
const result2 = foo({inOpt:false}) // number
const result3 = foo({}) // number
```

**UPDATE**
Without function overloading:

```js
type InputTrue = { inOpt: true }
type InputFalse = { inOpt: false }
type InputNone = {}
type Inputs = InputTrue | InputFalse | InputNone


type Infer<T> = T extends { inOpt: infer R } ? R : false;
type Mapped<T> = T extends true ? { outOpt: string } : T extends false ? { outOpt: number } : never;

type Result<T> = Mapped<Infer<T>>;

function foo<T extends Inputs>(arg: T): Result<T> {
    return arg as any as Result<T> // implementation is purposely skipped
}

const result = foo({ inOpt: true }) // string
const result2 = foo({ inOpt: false }) // number
const result3 = foo({}) // number
```

Comment: Apart from return type is directly `number` or `string` and not an object as I described (but this is quire easy to fix), interesting! I would prefer a solution which doesn't use function overloading.

Comment: Would recommend adding a link to the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: @DanieleRicci added example without function overloading

Comment: After some other attempts, I found the solution with function overloading to be the one which best fits my requirements. I had to use it even if I would have preferred a different one :D